Logic Programming languages supporting multiple scenarios and what-if
Is there any LPL that supports tracking multiple fact scenarios, identifying those that have become inconsistent, and performing what-if tests?
All the versions of Prolog I have seen have only a single fact space in which assertions can be made, even those with OOP support. CLIPS similarly can infer new facts about a given scenario, but doesn't seem to support switching between multiples.

Any Prolog implementation with a module system or a declarative object-oriented logic programming language such as Logtalk provides multiple namespaces. Dynamically switching between multiple namespaces (e.g. to apply the same reasoning over different scenarios) is quite simple in Logtalk. Your claims in the first sentence of your second paragraph are not correct.

A simple example that may be useful: https://logtalk.org/2019/11/13/many-worlds-design-pattern.html
